# Angular 2, ngrx, testing my Reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, rxjs, ngrx

In my Reducer file:

```
 case PumpActionTypes.EnterLocalMode:
  return commandOne.upsertOne(
    {id: action.payload.id, changes: { local: false }},
    state
  );
```

In my test, I want to test to see that `local` is changed to false.
What I wrote:

```
  describe('EnterLocalMode action', () => {
    it('should handle Enter Local Mode from Remote Mode', () => {


    const {initialState} = MyReducer;

    const action = new MyActions.EnterLocalMode();

    const state = MyReducer.reducer(initialState, action);

    //Test that the changes in pump adaptor change to "local" = true
    expect(MyReducer.commandOne.upsertOne(changes:{local})).toEqual(true);

      });



});
```

However, I'm not sure how to write my expect statement, which is right now incorrect:

```
expect(MyReducer.commandOne.upsertOne(changes:{local})).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: look edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reducer is a pure function which returns a new `state` based on `previousState` and `action`. So you should test that only.

```
expect(PumpReducer.reducer({counter:1}, Increment).counter).toBe(2)
```

suppose for `state = {counter:0}`, action `Increment` changes `state` to `{counter:1}`

You should test all actions like that and also any conditional branching in each action.

**Edit**

```
case PumpActionTypes.EnterLocalMode:
  return pumpAdapter.upsertOne(
    {id: action.payload.id, changes: { local: false }},
    state
  );
```

So you are returning state based on function call. And then

```
expect(PumpReducer.pumpAdapter.upsertOne(changes:{local})).toEqual(true);
```

it looks like you are testing if `upsertOne()` was called with `changes:{local}` or like that. You can use jasmine spyon method to check and test `arguments` of a function call.